# Magento2 add text to minicart while product added to cart

Tags: magento2, event-observer, mini-cart

In Magento2 - I want to add message on top of the `mini-cart` while product add to cart.

Using **event and observer** I want to add this message and also want to apply conditions for that, if **cart sub total less than (<) 100** then add message

> please add more product for a free shipping